# MvvmCross Navigate From ViewModel Event

Tags: c#, windows-phone, mvvmcross

I read about "ViewModel to ViewModel navigation" and "View Model Lifecycle" from here:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle

I can use Init() or Start() methods to initialise current ViewModel.
Also I can pass parameters from one ViewModel to another and receive it in the Init() method.

So my question:
When I created windows phone apps I used "NavigateTo" and "NavigateFrom" methods.
Init() is similar to "NavigateTo".
But I didn't find alternative for "NavigateFrom" method in mvvmcross and I don't know how to reload data when I move 'back' by "Close(this)" or using back button on windows phone.

Could you hint me?

Thanks in advance!

**updated**

I found out that Messenger (MvvmCross plugin) can help me with informing first ViewModel, when an other second ViewModel has changed data (for example add an item to a collection).
So when the second ViewModel add a new item, first ViewModel reloads the data in the OnCollectionChanged(CollectionChangedMessage obj) method.

Stuart showed how to work with this plugin in the NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/N-13-CollectABull-Part2.
Link here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-13-CollectABull-Part2

Answer (score 1):

> But I didn't find alternative for "NavigateFrom" method in mvvmcross and I don't know how to reload data when I move 'back' by "Close(this)" or using back button on windows phone.

In general, you don't need to reload data in this event - because the ViewModel is already created and initialised from the previous navigation in the forwards direction.

If you do want to do some refresh of the ViewModel when navigating back, then the `IVisible` pattern in the N=42 video may help but you'll need to add this to your View and ViewModel yourself - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/n42-is-my-viewmodel-visible-can-i-kill.html

Comment: "In general, you don't need to reload data in this event - because the ViewModel is already created and initialised from the previous navigation in the forwards direction."
Yes, I understand this. But the data, which first ViewModel uses, may have been changed by other second ViewModel, so I have to notify first ViewModel about this.
I found out that Messenger (MvvmCross plugin) can help me with this problem.